# How to revert pending `kops` changes?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, cluster-computing, kops

What I have done?

```bash
$ kops edit ig nodes  ## added some nodes by modifying min/max nodes parameters
$ ...                 ## did some other modifications
$ kops update cluster ## saw the pending changes before applying them to the cluster
```

In `kops update cluster` I saw some not desired changes and wanted to revert all of them and start over.
But given that the pending changes live in a state file in S3, I was not able to revert such changes easily.

I realized I should have had an S3 versioning enabled to revert the changes quickly and easily, but I didn't have that, and needed another way of cancelling pending changes.

Do you know how to achieve that?

PS. I googled for "kops drop pending changes" and similar; I browsed kops manual page; I tried accessing kops from multiple accounts before I realized that the changes are shared via S3... Nothing helped.

UPDATE:
See the https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/tutorial/working-with-instancegroups/, it says

> To preview the change:
>
> kops update cluster
>
> ```
> ...
> Will modify resources:
>  *awstasks.LaunchTemplate LaunchTemplate/mycluster.mydomain.com
>    InstanceType t2.medium -> t2.large
> ```
>
> Presuming you're happy with the change, go ahead and apply it: kops update cluster  --yes

So - what I want to do is to revert the not-yet-applied changes if i'm not happy with them. Is there any way other than `kops edit ig nodes` and manually changing `t2.large` back to `t2.medium`, repeating that for all changes I want to revert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the production cluster recommendations](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/getting_started/production/) states, storing the configuration in version control is recommended to avoid these scenarios.

But given that you are already facing a challenge now ...
It depends on what is introducing the change. If it is a change in your cluster config alone, reverting those changes would be the way to go.

If the changes comes from a kOps upgrade, there is no real way of reverting. kOps should never be downgraded, and the changes it tries to do are there for good reasons.

If you can share what the unwanted changes are, I may be able to determine how to revert them.

Comment: Well, the point I tried to make - is the the changes are not yet applied by kops. they are pending. And kops knows - somewhere internally - what is the current state and what is the pending state, and it shows the difference before you add "--yes" to the update command. So, can you drop the pending state? I just want to come straight to the "current state" and start making other changes.

Comment: Much of the diff comes from the kops client itself. So its diffing current state with what the new kops version wants to apply (e.g all addon updates). So thats what I mean by that there can be multiple sources for the changes.

Comment: I got the same diff from different account, on different PCs, so the "pending changes" are not something local - they should be stores in a shared place. But my question is not about the origin of pending changes - but how to discard them. Do you know how that can be achieved?

Comment: I only reiterate: the diff comes from using a newer version of kops than what was previously used, or they come from spec changes. There is only the applied state and the new state generated client side. The diff you see comes from diffing those two. There is no discard beyond reverting whatever change you did to the cluster spec. And again, if you share the unwanted changes, I can help you further.

Comment: The changes are intended changes, after I ran `kops edit ig nodes`. Not the changes related to usage of different kops versions.

So, I edited some instance groups, many of them, got some changes (e.g. 4 -> 5, 10 -> 15, 22 -> 13, etc.) and upon the review of those changes I'd like to revert or cancel or discard all of them, and then start over. How do I cancel those changes?

Comment: Assuming those numbers are max/min instances in an instance group, the diff is between your current configuration and what the AWS API returns. You need to set the values back to what you want them to be. If you want a mechanism for reviewing change, you need to use version control.

Comment: I know we're going back and forth, but the original question is still not answered.
Can I drop the non-applied changes?
As if you were using Microsoft Word or Notepad of some sort, opened a file, modified it and clicked "x". Then it says - "do you want to `save` or `discard`?".
In those terms, `save` would be equal to `kops update cluster --yes`. What `discard` equals to?

Comment: No. It's not possible for kops to infer what your config file should look like based on how your current AWS setup looks like.

Comment: Then how kops knows which changes to make when I actually do "kops update cluster --yes"? It should know what's in the AWS now, and what's pending, and then apply the changes if needed.

Comment: It diffs actual state with expected state using the aws api. But that doesn't mean it can take the aws api output and generate a kops config. Its sort of a one way street

Comment: not only that. it doesn't take just AWS current state. I think we're running in circles now.

Comment: from https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/tutorial/working-with-instancegroups/: QUOTE

To preview the change:

`kops update cluster <clustername>`

`Will modify resources:`
`*awstasks.LaunchTemplate LaunchTemplate/mycluster.mydomain.com`
`InstanceType t2.medium -> t2.large`


Presuming you're happy with the change, go ahead and apply it: `kops update cluster <clustername> --yes`


END QUOTE. 
So, what if I'm not happy with the change - how do i revert that?

Comment: For the changes you mention it only diffs with AWS state. If you are not happy with the change you need to change the values in your instance group spec.

Comment: it can not be the AWS state. some things, like min/max instances in the group when auto scaler is not enabled --- are stored somewhere outside of AWS. kops holds it somewhere, and it knows both "before" and "after"

Comment: Well... I wrote parts of that particular code and know quite well how it works. Min/max configures the AWS ASG and cluster autoscaler if enabled.

Comment: that's assuming is AWS is enabled, but it can be not enabled. but you brought a good point, can you share the part of the code that reads those XX -> YY pending changes in `kops update cluster`?

Comment: It's this function in the case of ASGs: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/b13b36a671dd30eb3c32b2e4c1f6f42136a9980b/upup/pkg/fi/cloudup/awstasks/autoscalinggroup.go#L103

Comment: Ok, interesting. I may be wrong, but before this moment I was 100% sure that in case when ASG are not used, I still can see the `Will modify resources: ... MaxSize                  8 -> 4; MinSize                  8 -> 4` messages from kops.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by ASG not used. kOps will always use ASGs for instance groups (except for the new Karpenter feature).